# How to speed up render time when frames repeat in V2.80 beta

Tags: rendering

I create a lot of technical animations and as such there are time delays between some transitions to make the presentation flow nicely. 
For example a device assembly scene where some components go together and between each component animation there is a 1 second gap. In this case for 25 frames, or whatever the frame rate is, each will be rendered. Adding another 40 minutes render time to each of these seconds, in my case.

Is there a way in blender to copy and repeat the previously rendered frame for those 25 frames where practically nothing happens, apart from showing a static image to the viewer for a second.

It would be great if someone could point me into the right direction so I could save many hours of render time that is really a waste.

I normally render into PNG and create a movie file from that in blender, if that would make a difference with possible solution.

Comment: Would it matter if you first rendered it to a lossless AVI video without the pauses? This would allow you to then load the complete video into the VSE and split the strip where the pauses are to occur. Stretch the left hand strip's right end and rejoin.

Comment: Kind of yes, because it gives extra processing and finding each point and then fill it with a static image. Not the best work flow.

Comment: I guess it comes down to whether each split and stretch would take more than 40 mins?  The VSE renders in a flash compared to cycles. (and Blender render for that matter)  Stretching only requires dragging the end of the split strip, then dragging the right strip back again.  They join automatically when you drag too far so there's not much time involved.

Comment: I use Camtasia for editing for final with text and text animation, transitions and so on but that is non distractive editing so dragging would not work. With Blender I am not so familiar with its VSE editing capabilities. No time for learning detailed use of VSE with current project. I will make time for it though but not now. With Blender setup I do other jobs while it is rendering but not actively doing on blender anything while it is rendering.

Comment: Concur with @Edgel3D.  Would render to images (imgnnn.fmt). with no pauses. Add pauses in VSE. Requires using only one strip type , hardly detailed or complicated. Add an image strip selectl images  (say) img001.fmt to img040.fmt. Add another strip with only  one image img040. (makes it 1 second long by default) then 41 to etc.  Quite possibly there is an addon to do this so you only have to enter the frames to pause and duration.